# Memory leak from SWIG-generated extension

Tags: php, memory-leaks, swig, php-extension

I'm having a memory leak problem wrapping a C++ library in PHP using SWIG. It seems to happen when callbacks from C++ containing complex types are sent to PHP while directors are enabled. Here is a standalone example to reproduce the leak:

Client.hpp:

```
#ifndef CLIENT_HPP_
#define CLIENT_HPP_

#include <vector>
#include "ProcedureCallback.hpp"

class Client {
public:
    void invoke(ProcedureCallback *callback) {
        callback->callback(std::vector<int>(0));
    }
};

#endif /* CLIENT_HPP_ */
```

ProcedureCallback.hpp:

```
#ifndef PROCEDURECALLBACK_HPP_
#define PROCEDURECALLBACK_HPP_

#include <vector>

class ProcedureCallback {
public:
    virtual void callback(std::vector<int>) = 0;
};

#endif /* PROCEDURECALLBACK_HPP_ */
```

So to use this, you create a `Client`, pass a subclassed `ProcedureCallback` to Client's `invoke` method, and Client then goes and calls the `callback` method of what you gave it, and passes an empty int vector.

This is the SWIG interface file:

```
%module(directors="1") debugasync
%feature("director");

%{
#include "Client.hpp"
#include "ProcedureCallback.hpp"
%}

%include "Client.hpp"
%include "ProcedureCallback.hpp"
```

Its output is very large, so I put it on pastebin instead: [debugasync_wrap.cpp](http://pastebin.com/ApQ7zGGb). Of interest in this file is probably SwigDirector_ProcedureCallback::callback (line 1319):

```
void SwigDirector_ProcedureCallback::callback(std::vector< int > arg0) {
  zval *args[1];
  zval *result, funcname;
  MAKE_STD_ZVAL(result);
  ZVAL_STRING(&funcname, (char *)"callback", 0);
  if (!swig_self) {
    SWIG_PHP_Error(E_ERROR, "this pointer is NULL");
  }

  zval obj0;
  args[0] = &obj0;
  {
    SWIG_SetPointerZval(&obj0, SWIG_as_voidptr(&arg0), SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_int_t, 2);
  }
  call_user_function(EG(function_table), (zval**)&swig_self, &funcname,
    result, 1, args TSRMLS_CC);
  FREE_ZVAL(result);
  return;
fail:
  zend_error(SWIG_ErrorCode(),"%s",SWIG_ErrorMsg());
}
```

This may also be of interest (line 827):

```
static void
SWIG_ZTS_SetPointerZval(zval *z, void *ptr, swig_type_info *type, int newobject TSRMLS_DC) {
  swig_object_wrapper *value=NULL;
  /*
   * First test for Null pointers.  Return those as PHP native NULL
   */
  if (!ptr ) {
    ZVAL_NULL(z);
    return;
  }
  if (type->clientdata) {
    if (! (*(int *)(type->clientdata)))
      zend_error(E_ERROR, "Type: %s failed to register with zend",type->name);
    value=(swig_object_wrapper *)emalloc(sizeof(swig_object_wrapper));
    value->ptr=ptr;
    value->newobject=newobject;
    if (newobject <= 1) {
      /* Just register the pointer as a resource. */
      ZEND_REGISTER_RESOURCE(z, value, *(int *)(type->clientdata));
    } else {
      /*
       * Wrap the resource in an object, the resource will be accessible
       * via the "_cPtr" member. This is currently only used by
       * directorin typemaps.
       */
      value->newobject = 0;
      zval *resource;
      MAKE_STD_ZVAL(resource);
      ZEND_REGISTER_RESOURCE(resource, value, *(int *)(type->clientdata));
      zend_class_entry **ce = NULL;
      zval *classname;
      MAKE_STD_ZVAL(classname);
      /* _p_Foo -> Foo */
      ZVAL_STRING(classname, (char*)type->name+3, 1);
      /* class names are stored in lowercase */
      php_strtolower(Z_STRVAL_PP(&classname), Z_STRLEN_PP(&classname));
      if (zend_lookup_class(Z_STRVAL_P(classname), Z_STRLEN_P(classname), &ce TSRMLS_CC) != SUCCESS) {
        /* class does not exist */
        object_init(z);
      } else {
        object_init_ex(z, *ce);
      }
      Z_SET_REFCOUNT_P(z, 1);
      Z_SET_ISREF_P(z);
      zend_hash_update(HASH_OF(z), (char*)"_cPtr", sizeof("_cPtr"), (void*)&resource, sizeof(zval), NULL);
      FREE_ZVAL(classname);
    }
    return;
  }
  zend_error(E_ERROR, "Type: %s not registered with zend",type->name);
}
```

And to demonstrate the memory leak in PHP ([debugasync.php](http://pastebin.com/NVpssSJS) is a set of proxy classes generated by SWIG which I have also uploaded to pastebin):

```
<?php

require('debugasync.php');

class MyCallback extends ProcedureCallback {
    public function callback($intVector) {}
}

$client = new Client();
$callback = new MyCallback();

while (true) {
    print(number_format(memory_get_usage()) . "\n");
    for ($j = 0; $j < 1000; $j++) {
        $client->invoke($callback);
    }
}
```

This prints memory usage, does 1k invocations, and repeats. Running it shows a quickly-growing memory space:

```
$ php test.php 
692,664
1,605,488
2,583,232
3,634,776
4,538,784
5,737,760
6,641,768
7,545,816
^C
```

Also of note is that if the C++ callback passes a primitive (i.e. `int`) instead of a complex type (i.e. `std::vector<int>`), there is no memory leak.

What is the cause of this memory leak?

And more generally, what tools can I use to solve this? Valgrind's massif hasn't really been able to narrow down what's going on, even after building PHP with debugging symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about SWIG specifically, but if the memory usage is reported by `memory_get_usage`, then the taken memory is allocated with the Zend Engine memory manager.

When the script finishes **cleanly** (no CTRL+C or `die`), the memory manager will tell you about the memory leaks it's found as long as:

- PHP is compiled in debug mode (`--enable-debug`)
- You have `report_memleaks = true` in your php.ini file

This will tell you where the memory that wasn't freed was allocated.

That said, there isn't anything specially funny with your snippet; the only non-stack allocated variable is properly disposed of.

Comment: I did 5,000 invocations in the above for loop with this enabled and PHP reported 5,000 memory leaks originating from line 860 of debugasync_wrap.cpp:

[Tue Aug  3 11:49:58 2010]  Script:  'test.php'
bin/cpp/debugasync_wrap.cpp(860) :  Freeing 0x085B96D0 (19 bytes), script=test.php
Last leak repeated 4999 times
=== Total 5000 memory leaks detected ===

I added efree(classname->value.str.val) before the FREE_ZVAL at the end. With that addition, PHP exits without a memory leak, but I still observe the same growing memory, though at a slightly slower rate (6.1M vs. 5.7M after 5k invocations).

Comment: @Ed Nice catch, I confess I don't use `FREE_ZVAL`, so I didn't know it didn't call the destructor. You can use `zval_ptr_dtor` or `zval_dtor` followed by `FREE_ZVAL`, you really shouldn't be freeing the string directly. As to your still growing memory usage without memory leaks reported... Maybe you're holding a resource somewhere, maybe it's normal. Try to add several more thousand invocations and check if PHP runs out of memory. (by the way, pick a username that has at least three characters before the space, otherwise notifications with @username won't work)

Comment: Thanks @Artefacto. It turns out the leak that PHP caught that was solved with efree() was indeed about 10% of the problem. The other 90% was solved by saying "$intVector = null" in the body of the callback. Using unset() didn't work because its reference count is 3 when it is passed to the callback (verified using xdebug).

Comment: @Edw I'm assuming the underlying zval had the reference flag on, because otherwise using `$intVector = null` should have the same effect as `unset($intVector)` in the reference count of the zval. (if the flag is set, `$intVector = null` leaves the ref count untouched but turns the zval into a PHP null, which would cause a call to `zval_dtor` on the previous value, thereby potentially freeing resources).